# Что означает данная строка c++?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

Перевожу код из c++ cli в c# и столкнулся с проблемой.
Что означает данный фрагмент когда

```
public ref class ConvertedString 
{
   static ConvertedString();
   private:
      ConvertedString(const wchar_t const * data, int ActualLength) :
      char_data(data),
      length(ActualLength)
      {
         ...
      }
}
```

Я понял, что создается приватный метод, с таким же названием как и класс, может я и ошибаюсь, но типа конструктора, который присваивает переменным значения после знака :

```
:
      char_data(data),
      length(ActualLength)
```

Но не могу понять, почему он приватный, и что означает данная строка `static ConvertedString();`

Замечу, что даже у этой строки `static ConvertedString();` есть какая то реализация, это как произошло то

```
static Matching::ConvertedString::ConvertedString() {
  init_model_cache();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static ConvertedString();` - это объявление [статического конструктора](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-define-and-consume-classes-and-structs-cpp-cli?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Static_constructors), специального метода, который вызывается исполняющей средой при создании домена приложений и может быть использован для инициализации глобального состояния класса. Реализация статического конструктора должна быть, видимо, где-то дальше в .cpp файле.

`ConvertedString(const wchar_t const * data, int ActualLength) ...` - реализация конструктора экземпляра объекта. Конструктор экземпляра может быть приватным по разным причинам: потому что существует другой конструктор, вызывающий его, либо для создания экземпляра должен использоваться статический метод.